# R: readBin and writeBin on linux

Tags: r, file-io

I want to write (and later retrieve) data in binary format. I am trying to get a minimal example to work at least to the level of the smell test (read input should look like written output), but I haven't gotten it just, and consistently right. My machine is a linux with little endian, but since that is constant here, I ommitted it from the calls. I was also not sure if it was better to specify the `size` argument in the write, or leave it out. At any rate, the loaded input doesn't look like `out`:

```
out<-seq(1,50,2)

##write
write<-file('~/output.txt','wb')
writeBin(out,con=write,size=4)
close(write)

##read
read<-file('~/output.txt','rb')
readBin(con=read,what=numeric(),n=length(out))
# [1] 3.200001e+01 3.276801e+04 1.048576e+06 1.677722e+07 1.006633e+08 4.026532e+08     1.610613e+09 6.442452e+09 1.503239e+10 3.006478e+10 6.012955e+10 1.202591e+11
close(read)
```

Comment: If you are only wanting to save binary data for later loading into an R session, you could/should instead use `save()` and `load()`. (`writeBin()` and `readBin()` really come into their own when you are wanting to transfer data to/from software outside of R.)

Comment: You override the value of `size` in `writeBin` but not `readBin`; hence the mismatch. Set both or neither.

Comment: I need to read the data later with `numpy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a worked example:

```
R> dat <- seq(1,50,2)
R> dat
 [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49
R>
```

We just write the object to a binary connection -- omitting your third parameter:

```
R> con <- file("/tmp/foo.bin", "wb")
R> writeBin(dat, con)
R> close(con)
R>
```

And can then read back:

```
R> con <- file("/tmp/foo.bin", "rb")
R> dat2 <- readBin(con, what="numeric", n=length(dat))
R> dat2
 [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49
R>
R> all.equal(dat, dat2)
[1] TRUE
```

However, you need to store the length.  I have used an internal file format which first writes a fixed (known) number of integers about rows, cols, "format number", ... and then read / writes a total of rows * cols numerics.  We also wraps this into a gzip-ed file connection.

You could even generalize this to writing columns as in a data frame -- but if R is your only reader / writer then the already exisiting serialization via `save()` is better.

Comment: The length thing is tricky. I often have `numpy`-generated files and I don't always know their length in advance.

Comment: That is _precisely_ our use case. I first wrote [RcppCNPy](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppCNPy) (to let R read/write NumPy files given an existing C library) but then replaced it with the solution described here which is even lighter / faster.  When we initially write the binary, we know the dims so we can write the header.