# r - efficient writeBin of a matrix of integers with varying binary size

Tags: r, binary

Let's say I have a matrix with 1,000,000 rows and 3 columns. All are integers.

I want to use writeBin to write it to a binary file.

However, I want the first and third column to be size=4 integers, but the second column be size=1 integer.

How can i write this matrix into a binary file efficiently?

*I know I can loop over each row of the matrix and write these elements one-by-one, but it would be very slow.*

Sample slow code below:

```
    DATA = matrix(as.integer(round(100*runif(3000000))), 1000000,3)

    i1=file("test.dat","wb")

      # How can I make this part below more efficient as its super slow now
      for (i in 1:nrow(DATA))
      {
        writeBin(DATA[i,1], i1, size = 4)
        writeBin(DATA[i,2], i1, size = 1)
        writeBin(DATA[i,3], i1, size = 4)
      }

    close(i1)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sapply` or any variant of `apply`?

Comment: @cgage No I haven't use any version of `apply`. How would that be more efficient? You mean to somehow encode the entire row to some object and then write it out? I don't understand how this can be done!

Comment: Me neither... i tried something like `sapply(DATA[,1],writeBin, con= i1, size = 4)` for each row, but this doesn't work properly, and is just as slow. I am beginning to believe there is no way to apply `writeBin` to a vector more efficiently than looping through the entire data table. Hopefully someone sees this and can help us out!

Comment: Why do you want to do that instead of using `save(DATA, file="test.dat")`?

Comment: @fishtank because binary file is being created to be used in another C# program rather than for R.

Comment: @cgage you don't need `sapply` to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368303/r-readbin-and-writebin-on-linux. It maybe faster to write column-wise rather than row-wise in your case. Or just use `size=4` always.

Comment: @fishtank well, the data should be written in specific format for the other application that needs it. So I don't have the luxury to change the format (it has to be row after row, and one of the integers are of size 1 and others of size 4).